# How to dynamically change form fields based on radiobutton selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form where I need to make it change dynamically based on radio button selection.
Suppose I have textfields Field A, Field B, ....,Field G and I have radio buttons Radio 1 and Radio 2 in a form.
I want to dynamically change the form based on radiobutton selection.
Form design is as follows :

```
Field A
Field B
Radio1 Radio 2
```

Now based on radiobutton selection, the other fields(Fields C to G) can be textfields or radiobuttons or dropdownlists. 
Now, I'm using two divs with the same fields with the view of their requirement(textfields or radiobuttons or dropdownlists) and hiding/showing those divs based on radiobutton selection.But is it the right way to do it. But the disadvantage I see with this method is each form field gets submitted twice(I mean it posts data from both divs even if one div is hidden)

How can I do this

Comment: You would have to also disable the hidden inputs to prevent then posting back (..disabled="disabled"..)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Correct. But, if I use disabled the problem is when I click the radiobutton the fields are disabled and we cannot enter anything.

Comment: do you have a single form?

Comment: When radio button 1 selected, remove disabled attribute from A and B and add disabled to C, D etc. When radio button 2 selected, do the reverse

Answer (score 0):

Setting a form element to disabled will stop it going to the server, e.g.:

```
 <input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="test"/>
```

To enable use this

```
$("id or class of the form field").prop('disabled', true);
```

To disable use this

```
$("id or class of the form field").prop('disabled', false);
```

On radio button selection you can do this.

Comment: At the same time I need to hide it

Comment: on the radio button click function you can hide the div as well as enable disable for the fields